# Setting an alternate url mapping for a servlet from a tomcat10 context

Tags: servlets, apache2, mod-jk, url-mapping, tomcat10

I have configured a system with apache2 with the mod-jk to access tomcat10 contexts that are configured in the `000-default.conf` as:

```
JkMount /app/* ajp13_worker
```

In this context, I have a servlet that looks like this:

```
@WebServlet(name = "File", urlPatterns = {"*.bin","*.html","*.css","*.js"})
public class File extends HttpServlet {
...
}
```

that creates mapping for url's like `http://localhost/app/page1.html`, `http://localhost/app/page2.html`, `http://localhost/app/page3.html`, etc. (there is other servlets here, that create mappings for others urls).

I wish that the servlet above also could create url mappings for `http://localhost/page1.html`, `http://localhost/page2.html`, `http://localhost/page3.html`, etc. If this not affect the other servlets, could be nice, but it is not required.